# Front wheel twist and move in dropouts when braking or on aggressive turns

Tags: mountain-bike, wheels, maintenance, repair, fork

I discovered that my front wheel moves on the dropouts. I have searched the web to know why? But most of answers was "replace quick release and problem gone" so I replaced the quick-release with different one. Not quite quick-release per se because it is allen bolt(you know hexagon shaped socket) but problem remain. It is quite tight right now I put some strength to tighten it up really good. So I looked at the old quick-release and saw this:

[image: worn out quick-release]

It this quite damaged in my opinion and I'm afraid that because of this my dropouts are damaged too. Could this be the case? How do I resolve this problem? What's to do when problem remain even with new quick-release? Fork is aluminium, wheel size is 29', disc brakes. I would love to provide any information that could help resolve this problem.

Comment: Did you replace it with a *good* skewer or just a different $15 external cam cheapie?  Skewers that are good for QR disc brake bikes aren't cheap.

Comment: I don't know the price for this one on photo but new one I bought is around $10 in USD

Comment: Could you recommend one that would be good? I don't really know much about that stuff. I heard that DT Swiss is good but I never seen any of this so I can't tell on my own. And they are quite pricey but if that would stop the problem I don't mind spending some money

Comment: The camless DT Swiss aftermarket ones are fit.  On places like eBay you will find cheap external cam OEM skewers branded DT Swiss that were meant to be installed OEM on bikes that have DT Swiss wheels but not the fancy skewer; they are probably not better than any other external cam skewer at that price.

Comment: camless means that lever of QR is embedded with part grip into dropout right? My current QR is like lever, part that grip into dropout, and cap that goes on the other side. And cameless would be lever with embedded grip into dropout and cap right? Or I'm missing something? Like this: https://www.jensonusa.com/DT-Swiss-RWS-Steel-Quick-Release ? And maybe stupid question but this work the same as regular QR lever up, lever down, open/close? And how it could be 50% more clamp strenght?

Comment: There is no cam, it's literally just a bolt with a built in wrench basically, you screw it tight, rather than 'flip' the lever over.  I have no personal experience using them on my own bikes.

Comment: Okey cool thank for the explaining gonna investigate that further but now I know whats going on thank you very much

Comment: I have a camless DT Swiss on my MTB front wheel, absolutely recommend them. They are proof of the adage "Quality is remembered long after cost of forgotten" (https://www.dtswiss.com/en/wheels/wheels-technology/rws-technology)

Comment: Consider moving to a through-axle fork and front wheel if you are riding hard enough to regularly cause this. I presume this is on a MTB.

Comment: I don't think that moving to through-axle is needed I'm riding this bike for maybe 4/5 years I don't remember exact date and this wasn't the case in the beginning. But first I'm going to replace QR again to DT Swiss I guess and if that don't resolve problem then idk I'm gonna toss myself from the cliff or something

Comment: Tightening skewers in the correct way is the most important factor.

Comment: What do you mean by that? You can tighten is only one way right? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

A lot of forks do this because the axle path is wrong. It needs to open forward to resist ejection force by disc brakes. The downward path was chosen to do the same for rim brakes. Many companies have made this switch, but not enough.

High-quality internal-cam QRs apply the most clamping force of any type. The simple answer is get any Shimano skewer. A better answer to this question would feature actual cam math, and I would welcome that, but barring that the above is usually a good starting place.

Dropout alignment can be a component of this problem as well. Being an aluminum fork, you'd have to replace the fork to do anything about it though if there was significant misalignment.

Comment: Shoot okey so going to buy something expensive this time and I hope this going to be it.

Comment: @StrudzonyWedrowiec It doesn't need to be expensive. Something like the Alivio/Tiagra-ish skewers with the aluminum lever would be totally fine.

Comment: Ok thanks for guidance I hope this will be enough